# Pulling the code from Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, repository

I am just getting into using Mercurial and I saw that someone was using the command

```
hg pull - - update -vvv
```

what does -vvv mean?

Thanks

Comment: That looks like an `ssh` flag (verbose)

Comment: That `- - update` doesn't look right.

Comment: @wRAR: Most likely that would be `--update`, which will update to the new branch head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% certain (`-vvv` isn't a standard switch in Mercurial), but `-v` on its own makes the output verbose.  When performing a verbose pull-with-update (`hg pull --update -v`), this outputs a tad more information, primarily which files are being updated, etc.

Running your command (using `-vvv`) has the same effect as `-v`, so Mercurial is treating it as a verbose switch.  The output certainly doesn't come out *more* verbose.

My guess is that the person in question has a stuck key :)